# Attach .mdf / .ldf files in SQL Server database from shared location in a local network

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Actually, I want to install a database from installer on remote machine SQL Server from server machine.

Comment: It is possible to attach files located on SMB shares -- you do that [in the same way as with other files](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/databases/attach-a-database) -- but it's probably not what you want. It sounds like you want backup/restore instead. In general, you almost never want to directly mess with data and log files unless you're moving them from one local disk to another.

Comment: The MDF/LDF files need to be on the local file system in order to perform restore.

Comment: @alexherm: SMB support was added in SQL Server 2008 R2 and expanded to all databases (user and system) in SQL Server 2012, following improvements made to SMB in newer versions of Windows that make this a realistic scenario. Restoring backup files from network shares (not attaching files directly) has been supported for longer than that, I think. Of course, whether you *want* the files to live on a network share is another matter, but it is supported.

Comment: Thanks for that Jeroen.  I haven't user SQL Server much in recent years, I expect you are correct.

Comment: [Running from network shares & NAS](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/01/sql-server-databases-on-network-shares-nas/)